# How to generate a file with current Day's hour with minute upto current time

Tags: shell, unix, awk

How to generate a file with current Day's hour with minute upto current time.

For exmaple if the time is `date '+%H:%M'` (02:28) i want the hour and minute as below.

```
Output:
00:00
00:01
00:02
00:03
.
.
.
.
02:28
```

Answer (score 1):

We just ran into a tricky situation on the job: there's one day each year in Brazil where there is no midnight. 00:00 is an invalid time. That's because the clock jumps forward at midnight by one hour.

A safe way to handle daylight savings is this:

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
    $tz    = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => "local"); 
    $local = DateTime->now(time_zone => $tz);
    $utc   = $local->clone->set_time_zone("UTC");
    $today = $local->strftime("%F");
    while ($local->strftime("%F") eq $today) {
        say $local->strftime("%H:%M");
        $utc->subtract(minutes => 1);
        $local = $utc->clone->set_time_zone($tz);
    }
' | tac > file
```

To demonstrate the Brazil "problem", try this and note that the first minute of the day is 01:00

```
perl -MDateTime -E '
    $tz    = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => "America/Sao_Paulo"); 
    $local = DateTime->now(time_zone=>$tz)->set(year=>2014, month=>10, day=>19);
    $utc   = $local->clone->set_time_zone("UTC");
    $today = $local->strftime("%F");
    while ($local->strftime("%F") eq $today) {
        say $local->strftime("%H:%M");
        $utc->subtract(minutes => 1);
        $local = $utc->clone->set_time_zone($tz);
    }
' | tac > file
```

Comment: Wait a min. It's not guaranteed that the time-jump due to daylight saving will always happen at T=00:00 it can happen at other time as well. e.g. check `zdump -v Europe/Chisinau | grep 2014`...

Comment: Yes that's right. That's why all date arithmetic is done in UTC, and I convert to the local time zone to display the time. The error I had at work was that I had some code like "give me a time object for midnight on such a day", and that threw an error for 2014-10-19 for the Brazil time zone. Working with datetimes is fascinating and infuriating simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Sufficiently self-explanatory:

```
h=`date +%H`
m=`date +%M`
eval printf '%s\\n' "{00..$((h-1))}:{00..59} $h:{00..$m}"
```

As pointed out by glenn, there is an issue of invalid time being logged, in case of day-light saving.
To handle such case, you can pass the above output via date command again. (slow)

```
eval printf '%s\\n' "{00..$((h-1))}:{00..59} $h:{00..$m}" | xargs -n1 date "+%H:%M" -d 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using AWK:

```
BEGIN {
    split(strftime("%H %M"),A,/ /)
    for (H = 0; H < A[1]; H++) {
        for (M = 0; M < 60; M++) {
            printf("%02d:%02d\n", H, M)
        }
    }
    for (M=0; M<A[2]; M++) {
        printf("%02d:%02d\n", H, M)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk way

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=((x=systime())-x%86400)}{while(x>i){print strftime("%H:%M",i);i+=60}}' <<< ""
```